# Is the power of a complex exponential signal always zero?

Tags: exponential-function, signal-processing

Is the power of a complex exponential signal always zero?

For example say I have the function

$ f(t) = Ae^{i\omega t}$

Then, I think power is defined as:

$P=\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} f^2(t) dt$

So is it such that for $f(t)=Ae^{i\omega t}$, $P=0$?

Comment: Check your definition again. For a complex-valued signal, I'm pretty sure that the power should be defined as $P = \int_{-T/2}^{T/2}|f(t)|^2 dt$ (note the absolute values).

Comment: Ah, thanks. That is where my error was.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{P}{A^2} = \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} e^{2i\omega t} dt
  &=     \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} \cos (2\omega t) + i \sin(2\omega t) dt \\
  &= \left. \frac{\sin(2\omega t) - i \cos (2\omega t)}{2i\omega} \right|_{-T/2}^{T/2}
\end{split}
$$
Remember that sine is odd, but cosine is even. Can you finish the problem?

Comment: There is a typo in your answer: you have "i" in cos() and sin(), which is not correct.

Comment: @Ali thanks, corrected. Next time, please feel free to make corrections directly